# Interfacing with a UVC 1.1 H.264 extension device with DirectShow

Tags: directshow, h.264, uvc

Working with DirectShow, I'm trying to get access to the H.264 stream of a Logitech C920 camera on Windows 8.

Using the Logitech drivers it seems the camera only exposes its H.264 output via the [UVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568651(v=vs.85).aspx) 1.1 H.264 extension.

Does anybody have a clear explanation of what needs to happen in order to query/initialize such a camera and subsequently use DirectShow to capture H.264 encoded video from the camera?